# Is there a simpler way to sum selected options in Webform computed_twig

Tags: webforms

I want to sum up all values of selected radios (all `q_` keys checked values) in a Drupal Webform form. Now I am doing it like this `{% set answersTotal = (data.q_1 + data.q_2 +  data.q_3 +  data.q_4 +  data.q_5 )|number_format %} {{ answersTotal }}` and it's working fine but I want a more efficient/simpler way to avoid having to type all the `data.q_#` as there are many `q_` in each group. I tried this (in a `computed_twig` element in Webform) with the [reduce](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/reduce.html) filter:

```
{% set questions = elements.qp1.ps1|filter((v,k) => k starts with 'q_') %} {# this is working fine #}
{{ questions | reduce((carry, v) => carry + v) }} {# this is triggering the error #}
```

The above is giving me an `Unsupported operand types` error.

I also tried this:

```
{{ questions.value | reduce((carry, v) => carry + v) }}
```

but it's giving me error:

```
The "reduce" filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "NULL" as first argument in "__string_template__33be2e0acc2d52a6558e04668185b54eb92d8ec87a21403496ffb5af73d8c9d1" at line 5.
```

The relevant line 5 in the twig template mentioned in the above error is:

```
echo $this->extensions['Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension']->escapeFilter($this->env, twig_array_reduce($this->env, $this->sandbox->ensureToStringAllowed(twig_get_attribute($this->env, $this->source, ($context["questions"] ?? null), "value", [], "any", false, false, true, 5), 5, $this->source), function ($__carry__, $__v__) use ($context, $macros) { $context["carry"] = $__carry__; $context["v"] = $__v__; return (($context["carry"] ?? null) + ($context["v"] ?? null)); }), "html", null, true);
```

I feel stuck and have no idea in what direction I should move and/or what materials for a newbie I should read to know what I am doing in a better and more organized/structured way.

Here is a minimal sample of my yaml code:

```
qp1:
  '#type': wizard_page
  '#title': 'Part I'
  '#open': true
  ps1:
    '#type': details
    '#title': title...
    '#required': true
    '#attributes':
      class:
        - qp1_1
    q_1:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q1.....
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
    q_2:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q2....
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
    q_3:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q3.....
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
    q_4:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q4.......
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
    q_5:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q5........
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
```

Comment: If someone writes a program, aren’t they a programmer?

Comment: Thanks @cilefen. I don't consider myself a programmer as long as I'm asking such question and still not sure what to do. I'm trying to learn and it's a long way still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a great clean solution and I hope it can save someone the frustration and hours of search and trials and reading to no avail like I did. I simply used this in my `computed_twig` template. Using a `for` loop to iterate through the `data` array and sum up the values of only the keys that start with `q_`:

```
    {% set sum = 0 %}
     {% for key, value in data %}
      {% if key matches '/^q_\\d+$/' %}
       {% set sum = sum + value %}
      {% endif %}
     {% endfor %} {{ sum }}
```

This is working perfectly as expected for my case and saves me having to type too many `data.q#` as per the number of the tens of questions I have.