# Naming standard for long webform elements keys/options for simpler resuable coding

Tags: webforms

I have a long multi-pages webform with mostly different groups of questions as radios, checkboxes, and likert types. I use computed_twig on some and jQuery on others for mostly either counting (how many of certain options/keys are selected) or summing up (the sum of keys values) selected values.

What's the most efficient strategy I can use and stick to so I can use less code/ re-use my code and need less re-coding for each group of questions (either with computed_twigs and/or jQuery).

The yaml code at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/315452/93899) is one example of my webform wizard pages.

And this is another sample/example where I need to count the number of all selected options of each name (e.g. how many "a" selected and how many "b"):

```
abqs:
  '#type': wizard_page
  '#title': 'test options length/count'
  '#open': true
  ab_1:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#options_display': buttons
    '#required': true
  ab_2:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#options_display': buttons
    '#required': true
  ab_3:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#options_display': buttons
    '#required': true
  ab_4:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#options_display': buttons
    '#required': true
  ab_5:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#options_display': buttons
    '#required': true
  abscore:
    '#type': computed_twig
    '#title': 'Selected a/b Counts'
    '#template': |-
      {# have yet to solve #}  
    '#ajax': true
    '#store': true
```